# Jungledisk for backing up my Wiki and Drupal sites?

Tags: backup, web-hosting, amazon-s3

Hi would you guys suggest that I ask my webhost to install Jungledisk so that my backups would be stored to Amazon S3 as well? Do you guys know a better solution?

Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 2):

So far I'm really liking jungle disk - I'm just now checking out their server version but I think we will be rolling it out here.

1. I don't see how it could hurt to ask them to install it if that is the way you want to go.
2. I don't know of any good competitors in the same feature / price range. Especially now that the rackspace cloud does not have transfer fees, and cost about the same for storage.

If we decided to move forward with jungledisk in a timely manner I'll update this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of crashplan... it's not S3 but its somewhat easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I am using JungleDisk on more than a dozen servers pushing changes to hosted files off-site nightly.  We also do local backups for fast recovery if a single server fails.  The thing with any Internet-based backup solution will be the time required to restore files.  Some services will put your data on a disk and mail it to you, but JungleDisk is not (as of this writing) in that category.  Use it for disaster recovery and a last-ditch way to get your files back, but don't rely on it as your primary backup as restore times will be long if you're pushing a lot of files around.